# Uploading coverage.ec file to sonar Android

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a coverage.ec file which gets generated and shows code coverage for my espresso UI tests. I also have sonar configured in gradle like so:

```
sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.projectName", "Android 9"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:Android9"

    property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
    property "sonar.username", "admin"
    property "sonar.password", "password"

    property "sonar.projectVersion", "5"

    property "sonar.java.source", "7"

    property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/outputs/lint-results.xml"

    property "sonar.sourceEncoding","UTF-8"
    property "sonar.sources","src/main/java"
    property "sonar.exclusions","build/**,**/*.png"
    property "sonar.test.exclusions", ""
    property "sonar.binaries", "build/classes"
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath","build/jacoco/testDevDebugUnitTest.exec"
    property "sonar.tests", "src/androidTest/java"
    //property "sonar.import_unknown_files", true

    //property "sonar.android.lint.report", "./build/outputs/lint-results.xml"

    property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/NORMAL/*.ec"
}}
```

problem? No code coverage at all is being displayed in sonar - nothing, 0% which is really odd and I haven't found anything online for the past week I've spent scavenging the internet. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What version of sonar do you use at your server?
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath is outdated according to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project#CodeCoveragebyIntegrationTestsforJavaProject-Usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of having *.ec for my reportPath, I changed it to be "coverage.ec". And then it showed up. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify test results to have your coverage handled by sonar.
Please also note that `sonar.jacoco.itReportPath` is outdated. Nowadays all coverage files are specifed with `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` property.

You don't have to specify source directories manually too. See `androidTest` property.

Here's the configuration for a project having both tests (like Robolectric) and android tests (like Espresso).

```
afterEvaluate {
    def flavor = "DEV"
    def variant = "devDebug"
    def testTaskName = "test${variant.capitalize()}UnitTest"

    // output both android and host test results to single directory
    def junitReportsPath = "build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/flavors/$flavor/"
    project.tasks[testTaskName].reports.junitXml.destination = junitReportsPath

    sonarqube {
        // you don't have to specify these manually as android sonar plugin handles it
        // as soon as you specify androidVariant
        // property "sonar.sources","src/main/java"
        // property "sonar.tests", "src/androidTest/java"
        androidVariant variant
        properties {
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths",
                    ["build/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec",
                     "build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/flavors/$flavor/*.ec"]

            property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", junitReportsPath

            // other settings
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```